# Java Login Servlet getting a internal error request HTTP 500 java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, arraylist

I'm working on a java web application that uses a login servlet for a jsp login page.  The login page action is set to go to the servlet but it won't load properly and I'm getting a HTTP 500 error.  I originally had an arraylist that stored the username and password locally in the java class that worked fine without the error until I changed it to pull the login data from a local mysql database using JDBC.  My database is setup with table for "user" that has all string data from the user class.

I ran a seperate java class to test the database and it seemed to run fine but when I tried to implement it into my web application it gave it errors within the LoginServlet.  I setup my AuthenicationService class to pull the user login data from the database and store them as objects in my arraylist. Not sure if there was a better way to do it but I didn't want to mess with my previous code that seemed to work ok prior to the changes. I'm sure there is a better way to do it but I'm kind of lost as to what to change so any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Here is the user class i have setup as my business logic layer:

```
public class User {
private String userName;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String phoneNumber;


public User(String userName, String pwd, String first, String last, String email, String phone) {
   this.password = pwd;
   this.userName = userName;
   this.firstName = first;
   this.lastName = last;
   this.email = email;
   this.phoneNumber = phone;
}


public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}


public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}


public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

private String getPassword(){
    return this.password;
}

private String getEmail(){
    return this.email;
}

private String getPhoneNumber(){
    return this.phoneNumber;
}

public boolean checkLogin(String userName, String pwd){
    return this.getUserName().equals(userName) && this.getPassword().equals(pwd);
}    
}
```

Another class setup that pulls the user login data from my database:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class AuthenicationService {
    ArrayList<User> users;


    public AuthenicationService()throws SQLException {
        String userName = null;
        String Password = null;
        String FirstName = null;
        String LastName = null;
        String Email = null;
        String Phone =  null;



        try {

        Connection myConn =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/titanbank_db", "root", "sesame");

        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

        ResultSet result = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from user");

        while (result.next()){
             userName = result.getString("UserName"); 
             Password = result.getString("Password");
             FirstName = result.getString("FirstName");
             LastName = result.getString("LastName");
             Email = result.getString("Email");
             Phone = result.getString("Phone");
             users = new ArrayList<User>();
             users.add(new User(userName, Password, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone));

     }   

        }
          catch (Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}


    public User login(String userName, String pwd){
        User actual = null;
        for (User me : users) {
            if (me.checkLogin(userName, pwd)){
                actual = me;
            }
        }
        return actual;
    }
}
```

Login Servlet:

```
import com.titanBank.bll.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("password");



        AuthenicationService service = new AuthenicationService();
        User user = service.login(userName, pwd);

        String url = "/accounts/accounts.jsp";
        String errorUrl = "/stderror.jsp";

        request.setAttribute("login", "true");



        if (user != null)
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
        else
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(errorUrl).forward(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

Error that I'm getting:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this     request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.titanBank.bll.AuthenicationService.login(AuthenicationService.java:56)
com.titanBank.controllers.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:41)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.9 logs.
```

Comment: Probably an exception occurs in AuthenicationService method thus the users ArrayList is null, and login method throws NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public User login(String userName, String pwd){
    User actual = null;
   if(users!=null){
    for (User me : users) {
        if (me.checkLogin(userName, pwd)){
            actual = me;
        }
    }
    return actual;

   }

   return null; 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried your suggestion and the error went away :)